# ReactJS multiple select on Form.Control does not mark selected objects

Tags: reactjs, forms, multiple-select

I have been trying to implement a multiple select but cannot see which items are being selected previously which is very confusing. This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StudentService from "../services/student.service";
import TeacherService from "../services/teacher.service";
import i18n from '../i18n';
import { Form, Button, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class CreateUser extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {
        isInCreationMode : false,
        name : undefined,
        headTeacherId : undefined,
        students : [],
        subjects : [],
        allStudents : undefined,
        allTeachers : undefined
      };
      this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
      this.handleHeadTeacherChange = this.handleHeadTeacherChange.bind(this);
      this.handleStudentChange = this.handleStudentChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.contains = this.contains.bind(this);
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      StudentService.getAllStudentsWithNoClassAssociated()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        response => {
          this.setState({
            allStudents: response
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            error:
              (error.response &&
                error.response.data &&
                error.response.data.message) ||
              error.message ||
              error.toString()
          });
        }
      );
      TeacherService.getAllTeachersWhoAreNotHeadTeachers()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        response => {
          this.setState({
            allTeachers: response
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            error:
              (error.response &&
                error.response.data &&
                error.response.data.message) ||
              error.message ||
              error.toString()
          });
        }
      );
    }
 
    handleNameChange = event => {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value })
    }
 
    handleHeadTeacherChange = event => {
        this.setState({ headTeacherId: event.target.value })
    }
 
    handleStudentChange = event => {
        var students = [...this.state.students];
        var chosenStudent = this.state.allStudents.filter(student => student.id.toString() === event.target.value)[0];
        if(students.map(stud => stud.id.toString()).includes(event.target.value)){
            if(chosenStudent){
                students.splice(students.indexOf(chosenStudent), 1);
            }
        } else {
            if(chosenStudent){
                students.push(chosenStudent);
            }
        }
        this.setState({students})
    }
 
    handleSubmit = event => {
        
    }
 
    contains = (array,value) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i].id === value){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container offset-md-1.5 spacing-before-and-after grey-font">
          <h2 className="padding-above-50px">{i18n.t('create class.new class')}</h2>
  
          <hr />  
            <Form validated={this.state.validated} onSubmit={(value) => this.handleSubmit(value)}>
                  <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="5" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1" />
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="2" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                          <Form.Label>{i18n.t('create class.name')}</Form.Label>
                          <Form.Control
                          name='name'
                          required
                          type="text"
                          isValid={this.state.name && !this.state.errorName}
                          isInvalid={this.state.errorName}
                          onChange={(value) => this.handleNameChange(value)}/>
                          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            {this.state.errorName}
                          </Form.Control.Feedback>
                      </Form.Group>
                  </Form.Row>
                  <Form.Row>
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1" />
                      <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                            <Form.Label>{i18n.t('create class.head teacher')}</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                            name='headTeacher' 
                            as="select" 
                            defaultValue={''}
                            isValid={this.state.headTeacherId}
                            isInvalid={this.state.errorHeadTeacherId}
                            onChange={(value) => this.handleHeadTeacherChange(value)}>
                                {this.state.allTeachers && this.state.allTeachers.map(teacher => 
                                    <option key={teacher.id} value={teacher.id}>
                                        {teacher.firstName + ' ' + teacher.lastName}
                                    </option>
                                )}
                            </Form.Control>
                            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            {this.state.errorHeadTeacherId}
                            </Form.Control.Feedback>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                  <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} md="3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1" />
                    <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                            <Form.Label>{i18n.t('create class.students')}</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control multiple className={'form-control-multiple-500px'}
                            name='students' 
                            as="select" 
                            isValid={this.state.studentId}
                            isInvalid={this.state.errorStudentId}
                            onChange={(value) => this.handleStudentChange(value)}>
                                {this.state.allStudents && this.state.allStudents.map(student => 
                                    <option key={student.id} value={student.id}
                                        selected={this.contains(this.state.students, student.id)}>
                                        {student.firstName + ' ' + 
                                        (student.middleName ? (student.middleName + ' ') : '') + 
                                        student.lastName}
                                    </option>
                                )}
                            </Form.Control>
                            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            {this.state.errorStudentId}
                            </Form.Control.Feedback>
                        </Form.Group>
                  </Form.Row>
              <Button type="submit" active={!this.state.errors} size="lg" className="spacing-beneath-50px spacing-above-25px">
                  {i18n.t('create class.save')}
              </Button>
          </Form>
          {this.state.message && (
              <div className="form-group">
                <div
                  className={
                    this.state.successful
                      ? "alert alert-success"
                      : "alert alert-danger"
                  }
                  role="alert"
                >
                  {this.state.message}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

What do you think may be the problem? I implemented my own contains in order to debug it. It returns true when I have 3 selected students (for example) but marked is only the last one added. How to have them all marked?

Answer (score 0):

What about just keeping the selected student ids in your state ? You can then just base on these ids to show a mark or not

```
handleStudentChange = (event) => {
    const selected = parseInt(event.target.value, 10)
    const { students } = this.state
    const newStudents = students.includes(selected)
      ? without(students, selected)
      : [...students, selected]

    this.setState({ students: newStudents })
  }
```

I'm using lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#without

Comment: Thank you for your response. The method handleStudentChange works fine - I did some debugging. But the problem is the students chosen are not marked in the Form.Control and the user may easily get confused which students were chosen already and which weren't. So basically the problem is with the `selected` prop of `option`

Comment: I see, it looks like react-bootstrap is not handling multiselect with feedback, maybe you can give a try with https://projects.skratchdot.com/react-bootstrap-multiselect/